# Cannot Get Route Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, debugging, config, router

As the title say explecitly, I don't manage to get some specific route I recently added. 
My symfony version : **2.8.18**. 
So here are the details :

Route I try to match :
 - /platform/cat
 - /platform/cat/{id}

File - **app/config/routing.yml** :

```
gb_platform:
resource: "@GBPlatformBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
prefix:   /platform
```

File - **GB\PlatformBundle\Resources\config\routing.yml** :

```
    gb_platform_home_:
    path :   /
      defaults: { _controller: GBPlatformBundle:Advert:index }

gb_platform_home:
    path :   /{page}
    defaults: 
        _controller : GBPlatformBundle:Advert:index
        page: 1
    requirements:
        page: \d*

gb_platform_view:
    path :   /advert/{id}
    defaults: { _controller : GBPlatformBundle:Advert:view }
    requirements:
        id: \d+

gb_platform_add:
    path :   /add
    defaults: { _controller : GBPlatformBundle:Advert:add }

gb_platform_edit:
    path :   /edit/{id}
    defaults: { _controller : GBPlatformBundle:Advert:edit }
    requirements:
        id: \d+

gb_platform_delete:
    path :   /delete/{id}
    defaults: { _controller : GBPlatformBundle:Advert:delete }
    requirements:
        id: \d+

gb_platform_cat:
    path :   /cat
    defaults: { _controller : GBPlatformBundle:Category:index }

gb_platform_cat_view:
    path : /cat/{id}
    defaults: { _controller : GBPlatformBundle:Category:view }
    requirements:
        id: \d+
```

File - **GB\PlatformBundle\Resources\controller\CategoryController.php** :

```
    <?php

namespace GB\PlatformBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

use GB\PlatformBundle\Entity\Advert;
use GB\PlatformBundle\Entity\Category;

class CategoryController extends Controller
{
    public function indexAction(Request $request)
    {

    }

    public function viewAction($id)
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $catRepo = $em
            ->getRepository('GBPlatformBundle:Category');
        $cat = $catRepo
            ->find($id);

        if($cat === null)
        {
            throw new NotFoundHttpException("L'annonce d'id ".$id." n'existe pas.");
        }

        return $this->render('GBPlatformBundle:Category:view.html.twig', array(
            'category' => $cat,
            ));
    }
}
```

At the origin, the routing.yml of the bundle was invalid. Once it's fixed, I try to get the both command :

> php app/console debug:router
>
> php app/console debug:router gb_platform_cat
>
> php app/console debug:router gb_platform_add

[image: Debug Router]

Each command were successfull and I saw no difference between /cat and /add while one match and the other don't.
I tried also many times to clear cache with :

> php app/console cache:clear --env prod

Still don't work. I'm confused ...
The error is basic : No route found for "GET /platform/cat/7

Comment: You say your routing file is `GB\PlatformBundle\Ressources\config\routing.yml`, please note you are using "Ressources" and not Resources like in your routing.yml: `"@GBPlatformBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"`. Is that the problem?.

Comment: Indeed my bad. It's a typing error specific to the topic.

Comment: Try to correct 4 blank spaces at the beginning in routing.yml in: `gb_platform_home_:` maybe is another typing error but it could be doing it working wrong. Yaml is a lot strict with blank spaces.

Comment: I was careful and I checked again. No error. I even submitted it to : http://www.yamllint.com/ . I think, the problem could be that rounting.yml not actualized as it should be. I tried to change controller of a route that match, and it used the old controller ...

Comment: another typo in `gb_platform_home` route you miss open and close {} in: `_controller : GBPlatformBundle:Advert:index`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally get the solution.

First of all be sure of the validity of the routing.yml files.
Additionnaly to usual symfony command (which will advice you of a mistake), you can use a validator like : [yamllint.com](http://yamllint.com)

In my case, routes config was correct. And I knew symfony could find them thanks to debug:router command and comparing them with other functional routes.

What I noticed, is that even changing the controller of routes that can matched, the update wasn't considered by the system. So obviously, it's a cache problem.

At the really begining I used, to reject this hypothesis, the command :

> php app/console cache:clear --env prod

But the problem was more global that the production environnement, so I solved my problem without specifying the env :

> php app/console cache:clear

The kind of mistake you do once, but not twice so it's .. ;)

Answer (score 0):

According to the [docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/routing.html#adding-wildcard-requirements), you need quotes around the pattern for requirements.

```
gb_platform_cat_view:
    path : /cat/{id}
    defaults: { _controller : GBPlatformBundle:Category:view }
    requirements:
        id: '\d+'
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it didn't solve the problem.
By the way, all the other routes match except those with '/cat' while format used for requirements is the same.

Answer (score -1):

You have defined /cat/7 not /platform/cat/7

anyway is better with annotation in controller instead of routing file:

```
/**
 * @Route("/platform/cat/{id}", name="gb_platform_cat_view")
 */
public function viewAction($id)
{

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $catRepo = $em
        ->getRepository('GBPlatformBundle:Category');
    $cat = $catRepo
        ->find($id);

    if($cat === null)
    {
        throw new NotFoundHttpException("L'annonce d'id ".$id." n'existe pas.");
    }

    return $this->render('GBPlatformBundle:Category:view.html.twig', array(
        'category' => $cat,
        ));
}
```

Comment: /platform is defined as default prefix in app/config/routing.yml. See the picture recently joined for debug:router.

Comment: its totally down to opinion whether or not someone uses annotated routing, theres a huge split on whether to or not, for a million different reasons on both sides.  Also, as it stands, your example wont help the OP because youve not told him how to change from yml to annotations, you need to tell the config.